Seens to be a lack of filament at layer starts
I'm kinda new to the 3D printing world, I got myself a Ender 3 V3 SE in the past month, been having pretty satisfactory results.
But recently I'm observing that right after the layer start position, (I looked at gcode, for the white dots that indicate where nozzle starts each layer) it seems that there's some filament missing there. Here are some examples:


I'm using Cura, since I had better (slower but better prints) than Creality Print. I don't know exactly what to try to fix that. Don't know if it's related do retraction, flow rate or other thing. I'm using the defaults profiles, with Standard Quality.
